LOD algorithm nanite's style: lod selection issue
I'm implementing a LOD algorithm nanite's style. So, the selection is for group of meshlets. I use the meshoptimizer lib to perform the simplification and meshlets creation and the METIS lib to group the meshlets. The LOD selection algorithm seems to choose the parent and the child at the same moment. So, in this way I have two LOD overlap as shown by this image:

I start thinking that the problem is how I create the parent-child relationship. In my code a child is linked to a parent if the meshlets “created” by the child is grouped to a parent. I use a std::map to link the meshlet ID to child group ID.
currentLod.lodVerticesMeshlets[i].meshletID = static_cast<idx_t>(i);
            if(prevLod)
            {
                //Meshlets generated by the child group
                prevLod->meshletToGroup.insert({currentLod.lodVerticesMeshlets[i].meshletID, groupID});
            }  

Then, when I group the mehlet, I use the meshlet ID to get back the child group and I create the relationship between parent and child:
//I'm binding the parent group with child one
                if(prevLod)
                {
                    /*I obtain the child group ID by using the ID of the meshlet, which is created from the 
                    simplified index of the child group.*/
                    idx_t oldGroupID = prevLod->meshletToGroup[meshlet.meshletID];
                    MeshletGroup* oldGroup = &totalGroups[oldGroupID];
                    
                    //I want avoid repeated values
                    if(std::find(oldGroup->parentsGroup.begin(), oldGroup->parentsGroup.end(), group->groupID) ==
                    oldGroup->parentsGroup.end())
                    {
                        //The new group is the parent of the old group
                        oldGroup->parentsGroup.emplace_back(group->groupID);     
                    } 
                }

Where am I going wrong?

//I want avoid repeated values -- Why not use a std::set if you want to avoid duplicates?

Because I need a vector to pass it to a compute shader. I had already thought to use a set but I prefer a vector

Where am I going wrong? -- Since this is not a [mcve], the general answer is that your code has one or more bugs.
